# General SQL execution using IDBconnection

Tags: c#, sql, database, interface, idbconnection

Is it possible to execute a query using IDBConnection? I have a factory class returning IDBConnection and I don't want to cast it back to SQLConnection in order not to expose implementation. So how can I execute a query using IDBConnection?

Comment: Check the examples from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idbconnection?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy there is only one problem. IDBCommand has no parameters.Add() so how can I prevent SQL ejections?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idataparametercollection?view=netcore-3.1 says it has an `Add`.